One IO to control two LEDs. When one is lit, the other is not
I am currentlly running out of IO ports on my Arduino board.  Yes, I also have several IO extendor boards.  The constraint isn't the number of IO ports, it's the wiring to the remote 'Station' via RJ45/Cat5 cables, which only has eight wires.
To simplify, each 'Station' has two LEDs, requiring two IO ports.  These LEDs always toggle.  When one is lit, the other is not.  Each 'Station' has access to ground and 3.3 V.  I would like to know how I can control two LEDs that will always toggle using just one IO port.  When the IO is HIGH red is lit and green is unlit, when the IO is LOW, red is unlit and green is lit.

Connect one LED + resistor between the I/O pin and ground and the other LED + resistor between the same I/O pin and VCC.

How much current does each LED use?

Does the wire that drives the come directly from your Arduino or from GPIO expander? In the latter case, the GPIO expander type is important, as it may cause limitations what kind of circuits are possible, depending on the output type. It may invalidate a lot of the given answers.

And nobody suggests a NOT gate? Why not?

@ThomasWeller, because it requires an unnecesary extra component. Not gates are used in the answer, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/723025/73158.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A circuit I have used many times with chips that provide a high/low status output (eg battery charger chips). Note that a bicolour LED can also be used.
Looks similar to Transistor's answer, but avoids the situation where (if the GPIO is not driven) that both LEDs would glow dimly.
When GPIO is high, bottom LED lights. When GPIO is low, top LED lights. When GPIO is floating, neither lights.

Snap! http://lednique.com/gpio-tricks/1-gpio-bi-colour-2-pin-led/

(Red should need at least 1.6 V, green 1.9 - sums to > 3.3.)

@greybeard Why would you sum the Vf of the LEDs? they are not in series.

(They are in Transistor's proposal where dimly emit the sum would need to be about the supply voltage.)

What values of the resistors do you need with this? Note that the original question states they only have access to 3.3V and need to show a red and green led. With a 5V supply, it is easy to pick just 2 resistors of the same value, but how do you pick them in this case?

I think the galvanic connection between the resistors harmful here (if at any time you want both LEDs off).

@Ferrybig pick them for the brightness wanted red & green.

Thanks!  Once you see the answer, it became obvious.  Here's what I did:
RED LED: Anode to GPIO, Cathode to Ground.
GRN LED: Anode to 3.3V, Cathode to GPIO.
SImple.  Elegent.  AWSOME!

@Ferrybig I hadn't thought about the exact values too much, but the values you would choose for independent operation would be conservative (since some of the current would be shunted by the other resistor). I guess I would probably work out what voltage the middle node would be, which sets the ratio of the resistors and then work from there.

You may want to edit the schematic to label the resistors R1 and R2 so that people who are familiar with the American resistor symbol (⌇) don't erroneously think there are no resistors used at all.

With 3.3V supply, it seems like the resistor middle point would be at 1.65 V and you couldn't use this with anything except red leds.


Figure 1. Image source (mine) from LEDnique.com.

When GPIO is pulled low R1 and L1 conduct.
When GPIO is pulled high R2 and L2 conduct.

The schematic shows 5 V but, depending on the LEDs, it will work on 3.3 V.

It won't work on 3V3, because LEDs don't exist that'll sum to less than that. Even for two red LEDs it's marginal, and green are always a higher voltage. It's 5V or nothing here, I'm afraid.

You could consider that a feature, e.g. when a microcontroller is initialising or has failed with the GPIO set in a power up default of input (as is common), both LEDs will light indicating an obvious fault condition.

@Graham, we're only trying to light one LED at a time - not both.

@Graham Why? With the GPIO (and VCC) at 3.3V, R2-L2 sees 3.3V and R1-L1 sees 0V; and with the GPIO at 0V, it's the reverse.

Graham - incorrectamundo.

Thanks! Once you see the answer, it became obvious. Here's what I did: RED LED: Anode to GPIO, Cathode to Ground. GRN LED: Anode to 3.3V, Cathode to GPIO. SImple. Elegent. AWSOME!

No current limiting resistor?

Perhaps I should put resistors in, but the LEDs seam to work just fine without them.   This is a test layout.  Once we build the real 'stations', we'll most likely ensure the proper resistance for each led.  This circuit is 3.3V using a Huzzah32, which is only capable of 3.3v.  I may need to scale up to a different board becuase other componetry, like relays, need 5v.  Inwhich case, we'll definately need resistors   for the LEDs.

@Transistor Ah, you're right of course. My apologies! (I'd delete my comment, but then the replies would look odd.)

@Graham, thanks. Don't worry about it.

@Dan lemme Guess: Arduino? Just as a note: Never ever (and I mean NEVER) run a LED without some sort of current limiting device. "It works" is no excuse. I know, you're seeing a lot of that crap in Arduino Forums but we're here on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange and to stuff the right way :D

3.3V is even an advantage here. With GPIO floating, current would have to flow through both LEDs, and 3.3V is not enough for that.

@kruemi  What value of current-limiting resistor do you propose?

@kruemi.  I totally appreciate your comment and will ultimately satisfy the EE's in the room.  LIke I said above, I am scaling up the board to handle 5v output, so willl definately use resistors with the 100's of leds in this project (just not looking forward to it). So, what resistors would be appropriate for a 5v supply?

@Dan, see if http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/loadline-resistance-graphic-tool/ is of any use.

@MikeB  about the value of the Resistor: That depends in the Diode you use and the supply voltage. The diode you use determines the current you want trough the diode and the voltage drop to expect at that current. So R = (Usource - Udiode)/Idiode.

@kruemi  Let me re-phrase that - you say "Never ever (and I mean NEVER) run a LED without some sort of current limiting device."  If you have an LED that is rated at 2.0v and a voltage difference of 1.9v  (which seems to be the case here) what do you propose??

The current limiting can be in the power source. See Battery and LED without resistor.

@MikeB because look at the Voltage/Kurrent curve of an LED (or any LED for that matter). It's highly non linear and you'll get huge differences in current with small changes in voltage. So just normal tolerances in voltage sources can mean the difference between "barely glowing" and "destroyed by overcurrent".

@Transistor that's why I wrote "current limiting device". If your source is reliably current limiting, go with it. But the output of an uC is not made for current limiting...

Often, a GPIO pin cannot source as much current as it can sink.  If this is the case, here is a trick that relies on sink current only. The center schematic is the one for your application.  Your GPIO pin replaces the gate, and is connected directly to D3.
The combined forward voltage of D4 plus D5 is greater than the Vf of D3.  When the D3 cathode is low, D3 effectively "shorts out" D4-D5.  The same circuit works with the LEDs transposed.


Basic idea
A minimalistic circuit solution can be implemented with only three elements - a resistor and two LEDs; it is only necessary that the LED forward (threshold) voltages meet the requirements VLED1 + VLED2 > Vcc and VLED1 (VLED2) < Vcc. In the conceptual schematics below, I have modeled the LEDs by forward-biased "ideal" diodes with 2 V threshold voltages.
Conceptual 3.3 V diode circuit
The microcontroller output (not shown in the schematics below) consists of two complementary transistors which may not connect the output to the supply rails (high output impedance) or connect it either to ground (low output voltage) or to Vcc (high output voltage). I have modeled it here in the simplest possible way with a piece of wire.
High output impedance
In this case, the left hand resistor end is unconnected (floating). Although the string of two LEDs in series is connected between the supply rails, both LEDs are off since the overall threshold voltage of the string is higher than the supply voltage. No currents flow in the circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Low output voltage
Now the resistor is connected to ground; so a current flows through LED1 and it is on.

simulate this circuit
Middle output voltage
During the transition, when the voltage is between Vcc - VLED1 (1.3 V) and VLED2 (2 V), the circuit state is similar to the high impedance state - both LEDs are off and no currents flow.

simulate this circuit
We can see it in the DC sweep simulation.

This state is not essential in such a digital application because the microcontroller output voltage quickly jumps this 0.7 V "dead" zone, but it may have some analog application (LED voltage indicator).
High output voltage
Here the resistor is connected to Vcc; so a current flows through LED2 and now it is on.

simulate this circuit
All diode versions
Finally, let's investigate and compare the three versions proposed in the answers here.
Version 1: R-LED circuits shunted
Here, two R-LED circuits are connected in series to the power supply. The input voltage source (microcontroller output) shunts one circuit so its current is diverted and the LED is off, and connects the other circuit to the power supply so a current flows and the LED is on.

simulate this circuit

(+) Reliable LED shutdown
(-) Redundant resistor
(-) Requires VLED1 + VLED2 > Vcc
Version 2: LEDs shunted
In this case, only the two LEDs are connected in series to the power supply, and the two resistors are replaced by one common resistor. The input voltage source connects the resistor in parallel to one LED so its current is diverted and the LED is off, and connects the other LED to the power supply so a current flows and the LED is on.

simulate this circuit

(+) Only one resistor
(-) Requires VLED1 + VLED2 > Vcc
Version 3: Back-to-back LEDs
Here, a network of two LEDs in parallel, back-to-back, is connected between the input voltage source and the output of a .5x voltage divider supplied by Vcc. Thus, the right hand end of the LED network is "lifted" with Vcc/2, so the voltage across it tries to change from -Vcc/2 to Vcc/2 (but actually is limited to the voltage of the forward-biased LED).
Unsuccessful 3.3 V solution: Unfortunately, the  (1.65 V) voltage across the forward-biased LED is insufficient to turn it on.

simulate this circuit

Successful 5 V solution: So, this configuration needs a 5 V power supply. Then a 2.5 voltage produced by the voltage divider is applied to the 2 V forward biased LED (the current is limited by the Thevenin divider resistance).

simulate this circuit

(+) Reliable LED shutdown
(-) Redundant resistor
(-) Requires VLED < Vcc/2
See also another related answer of mine.

Did you see some feature of this entire question that isn't a duplicate?  When you find yourself copying this much of an existing answer, should set the "it's a dupe" spidey-sense tingling.

@Ben Voigt, this is a 3.3 V version with adapted schematics, graphs, and text, and a new section added. At the end of my answer, I have attached a link to the original 5 V answer. So, there is nothing hidden. I would appreciate it more if you commented on the substance of the written.

Here is yet another scheme that could be useful with two-pin bipolar LEDs. The IC could be 1/3 of a 74HC14 hex ST inverter or something like a dual inverter.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Input High = Red
Input Low = Green
Input High-Z = Yellow

Interesting... Looks like (at input H-Z) the left HC14, C1 and R1 form a relaxation oscillator (due to HC14's hysteresis); so the yellow is a result of the fast switching between the red and green?

@Circuitfantasist Yes, exactly.

1 GPIO, 2 LEDs
For a single GPIO pin, there are two basic circuits. The first one uses two resistors and lets you light D1 or D2 alternatively, but they cannot be both turned off. The second circuit turns the LEDs off when GPIO is switched from output to input (i.e. becomes Hi-Z, high impedance).



GPIO
LED

GPIO
LED




0
D1

0
D3


1
D2

1
D4





Z
off



In either circuit, both LEDs can appear  lit "simultaneously" by driving a square wave onto GPIO

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
2 GPIO, 4 LEDs
Two GPIO pins can control 4 LEDs, including the OFF state.



GPIO1
GPIO2
LED




0
0
D1


1
0
D2


0
1
D3


1
1
D4


Z
0 or 1
off




simulate this circuit
The tristate detector outputs an active-low signal when GPIO1 is tri-state. See Tri-State Detection for more ideas.

simulate this circuit
2 GPIO, 8 LEDs
Fully utilizing 3-state logic lets us control 8 LEDs + an off state, since 32=8+1.



GPIO1
GPIO2
LED

#G1TRI
#G2TRI




0
0
D1

1
1


1
0
D2

1
1


0
1
D3

1
1


1
1
D4

1
1


Z
0
D5

0
1


Z
1
D6

0
1


0
Z
D7

1
0


1
Z
D8

1
0


Z
Z
off

0
0




simulate this circuit

Isn't it better in the transistor circuits to swap the base and emitter (CE configuration)? Because in this CB configuration, the LED current flows into/from the microcontroller output (as in diode circuits) and the transistor role becomes meaningless...

@Circuitfantasist The transistor pair acts as switches that are both off when GPIO is floating (Hi-Z). It’s OK for the microcontroller to drive the LEDs, they don’t need much current. With transistors, a Hi-Z condition will keep both LEDs off. I have not looked yet at how the CE circuit would work. The CB switch is a common building block though. It has an arbitrarily low forward voltage drop - it can be configured to be in mild saturation and retain high speed while not slowing down the logic. Good for logic level translators and current switches (ECL-style a bit).
